# Installing Visual Studio without restart

Tags: visual-studio

I would like to install Visual Studio (Community edition) on a server that is used by other individuals. The installation requires a restart to complete the process. Is there any way to complete the necessary steps manually without restarting the server?

Comment: Have you tried just running it after the installation completes?   Depending on what features you installed, it will probably just work.

Comment: Yes, the message I receive is "A reboot is pending. Please reboot before starting Visual Studio."

Comment: Then you'll need to reboot.

Comment: I know this is useless, but is is possible to see what services need the reboot in order to run the software? If so, could you try rebooting them individually and report back if it works? Either way, a reboot is recommended, probably schedule one tonight if you can.

Comment: Well, that's the question: Is it possible to perform the necessary steps manually? A reboot is not an option.

Comment: I don't think so! Visual Studio will make some changes in the operation system too, and you will notice updated on your system after restarting your server, I have just install it yasterday, and noticed updated comes with "Community edition"

Comment: Normally .NET 4.5.2 is the one that causes VS to need a reboot.

Answer (score 4):

Silently installing Visual Studio is more difficult than it should be. On a Win2008R2 you will need to install .Net 4.5 seperately before running the visual studio installer.

On both 2008R2 and 2012 you will also need custom AdminFile that disables a lot of the optional stuff like SQL and Office Tools. This XML used by a Chocolatey package should result in a silent installation: https://github.com/mwrock/Chocolatey-Packages/blob/master/VisualStudio2012Ultimate/Tools/AdminDeployment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AdminDeploymentCustomizations xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2011/AdminDeployment">
   <BundleCustomizations TargetDir="default" NoWeb="yes"/>
   <SelectableItemCustomizations>
     <SelectableItemCustomization Id="WebTools" Hidden="no" Selected="no"/>
     <SelectableItemCustomization Id="SQL" Hidden="no" Selected="no" />
     <SelectableItemCustomization Id="OfficeTools" Hidden="no" Selected="no"/>
     <SelectableItemCustomization Id="SharepointTools" Hidden="no" Selected="no"/>
     <SelectableItemCustomization Id="LightSwitch" Hidden="no" Selected="no"/>
     <SelectableItemCustomization Id="SilverLight_Developer_Kit" Hidden="no" Selected="no" />
     <SelectableItemCustomization Id="VC_MFC_Libraries" Hidden="no" Selected="no" />
     <SelectableItemCustomization Id="Blend" Hidden="no" Selected="no" />

     <SelectableItemCustomization Id="BlissHidden" Selected="yes" />
     <SelectableItemCustomization Id="HelpHidden" Selected="yes" />
     <SelectableItemCustomization Id="IntelliTraceUltimateHidden" Selected="yes" />
     <SelectableItemCustomization Id="LocalDBHidden" Selected="yes" />
     <SelectableItemCustomization Id="NetFX4Hidden" Selected="yes" />
     <SelectableItemCustomization Id="NetFX45Hidden" Selected="yes" />
     <SelectableItemCustomization Id="PortableDTPHidden" Selected="yes" />
     <SelectableItemCustomization Id="PreEmptiveDotfuscatorHidden" Selected="no" />
     <SelectableItemCustomization Id="PreEmptiveAnalyticsHidden" Selected="no" />
     <SelectableItemCustomization Id="ProfilerHidden" Selected="yes" />
     <SelectableItemCustomization Id="ReportingHidden" Selected="yes" />
     <SelectableItemCustomization Id="RIAHidden" Selected="yes" />
     <SelectableItemCustomization Id="SDKTools3Hidden" Selected="yes" />
     <SelectableItemCustomization Id="SDKTools4Hidden" Selected="yes" />
     <SelectableItemCustomization Id="Silverlight5DRTHidden" Selected="yes" />
     <SelectableItemCustomization Id="SQLCEHidden" Selected="yes" />
     <SelectableItemCustomization Id="SQLCEToolsHidden" Selected="no" />
     <SelectableItemCustomization Id="SQLCLRTypesHidden" Selected="yes" />
     <SelectableItemCustomization Id="SQLDACHidden" Selected="yes" />
     <SelectableItemCustomization Id="SQLDbProviderHidden" Selected="yes" />
     <SelectableItemCustomization Id="SQLSharedManagementObjectsHidden" Selected="yes" />
     <SelectableItemCustomization Id="StoryboardingHidden" Selected="no" />
     <SelectableItemCustomization Id="TSQLHidden" Selected="yes" />
     <SelectableItemCustomization Id="VCCompilerHidden" Selected="yes" />
     <SelectableItemCustomization Id="VCCoreHidden" Selected="yes" />
     <SelectableItemCustomization Id="VCDebugHidden" Selected="yes" />
     <SelectableItemCustomization Id="VCDesigntimeHidden" Selected="yes" />
     <SelectableItemCustomization Id="VCExtendedHidden" Selected="yes" />
     <SelectableItemCustomization Id="WCFDataServicesHidden" Selected="yes" />
     <SelectableItemCustomization Id="WinJSHidden" Selected="yes" />
     <SelectableItemCustomization Id="WinSDKHidden" Selected="yes" />
   </SelectableItemCustomizations>
</AdminDeploymentCustomizations>
```

Then finally you need to add /quiet and /norestart to your command:

```
vs_professional.exe /adminfile \\FQDN\Share\AdminDeployment.xml /quiet /norestart
```

If you just ran the installer I don't think you can avoid a reboot.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee225237(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: .NET 4.5.2 normally is the culprit for the reboot. Your answer just removed it from the picture